# Why does including <windows.h> result in "error: expected ')' before numeric constant" on an unrelated #define statement

Tags: c++, c, mingw, portability, mingw-w64

Can anybody explain what is going wrong here?  When I try to compile [qtermwidget](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget) under [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org), and adding [`#include <windows.h>`](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/windows.h) to source file [BlockArray.cpp](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget/blob/master/lib/BlockArray.cpp), I get the following compile error relating to `#define BlockSize (1 << 12)` in [BlockArray.h](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget/blob/master/lib/BlockArray.h):

```
In file included from E:/git/qtermwidget/lib/BlockArray.cpp:27: 
E:/git/qtermwidget/lib/BlockArray.h:30:20: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
30 | #define BlockSize (1 << 12)
   |                   ~^
```

Why is the addition of the [windows.h](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/windows.h) header causing this error?  Assuming I really want to add this header, can I change the `#define BlockSize (1 << 12)` in [BlockArray.h](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget/blob/master/lib/BlockArray.h) somehow to not break the compile?

Comment: Perhaps `windows.h` defines `BlockSize`, inside it, in some way, and the end result of this macro is a big, ugly mess?

Comment: Sam could be correct here, have you tried renaming it? That is a risky name to choose. How are you using the macro?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think that's it, I was thinking it must be something odd in the (1 << 12) value definition, but you're right it just seems to be a duplicate macro name.  Please add as answer.

Comment: Most compilers provide an option to produce the intermediate source after preprocessing. If I encountered such preprocessor problems,I found it mostly helpful to look at the resulting source.

Comment: @thebusybee, thanks, I did try using -E and -dM with gcc to get preprocessed output and a list of defines.  Unfortunately that didn't help in my case (see answer), but yes this is definitely a good first step in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks very much to Sam and busybee, I can confirm that there is a name conflict in [winnt.h](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/49e9a673b36a1241747bf3ea95d040f127753f81/mingw-w64-tools/widl/include/winnt.h) which is brought in via [windows.h](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/windows.h).  It's a typedef using the 'BlockSize' name, rather than another preprocessor definition, however:

```
typedef struct _TAPE_SET_MEDIA_PARAMETERS {
    ULONG BlockSize;
} TAPE_SET_MEDIA_PARAMETERS, *PTAPE_SET_MEDIA_PARAMETERS;
```

Changing the `#define BlockSize (1 << 12)` in [BlockArray.h](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget/blob/master/lib/BlockArray.h) to a new name, e.g. `#define LXQT_BlockSize (1 << 12)` resolves the conflict.

Comment: Poor design on the part of the qtermwidget library; a good solution would be `enum { BlockSize = 1 << 12 };` which has no possibility of preprocessor clashes

Comment: @M.M: On the other hand, the qtermwidget library author might say "don't run Windows."

Comment: @Joshua Yeah if they wanted to double down instead of admitting their mistake . The same problem would occur with any other library that happened to use BlockSize too .

Comment: @M.M: Whose mistake? `windows.h` is the worst namespace polluter I've ever seen.

Comment: @Joshua qtermwidget is unnecessarily polluting the namespace in the case in this question; "someone else pollutes the namespace too" is no defence